# Offline-first database instead of sqlite

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, electron, nosql

I found a big, HUGE problem with `sqlite3` module. when i try to build for windows, it doesn’t work due to issues between sqlite module and `electron-builder`.

i was thinking to change te database to something that still works offline.
It’s not important that is a RDMS or NOSQL (all the data are stored in json files on a soap services which i transform in sqlite statement)

the important (vital) issue is that it must work offline.

i've been trying just packing the app using `electron-packager`

Answer (score 1):

If your main concern is that It should work offline I will recommend give a try to [Indexeddb](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_indexeddb.htm) it stores data into the users browser.

Comment: i was looking at indexeddb too, and i was searching for its limitations, such as file size (actually my project has 2 databases of 150 and 500 MB) but i didn't find nothing about that...

Comment: ok.. indexeddb is out of my choice because i need to separate data file (the database) from my application (it's made on electron, so for app update and asar compatibility issues i need to take them in different locations)

Comment: I understand your limitations, give [pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/) a try it might be helpful.

Comment: last 2 choises are pouchdb and nedb...i'm still searching and learning, but NeDB seems to lack of documentation and examples / tutorial..

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials and articles for pouchdb and an npm library is also available [pouchdb-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-node).